# How to remove borders in TableView header in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, tableview

I'm using `TableView` in many places in my javaFX application. I'm working on a dark mode theme and want to style this table. Now i can't manage to remove the borders in the header row. Also, the text color in the table rows remains black although the rest of text appears white (because of a dark color for `-fx-base` in root css class) in my application. The table looks like this:

[image]

The css:

```
.root {
-fx-base:#292929;
}

.table-view {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
   -fx-border-color: all-dialog-border-color;
   -fx-border-width: 1;
   -fx-table-header-border-color: transparent;
   -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
   -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.table-view .column-header-background
{
   -fx-background-color: -fx-base;
}

.table-row-cell
{
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
.table-column {
  -fx-alignment: CENTER;
}

.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:focused {
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
}
```

I want to remove the borders between the columns in the header and make the text in table rows appear white. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just play with this Css, it should give you all the customization you want

```
.table-view{
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-font-size: 20px;
    -fx-border-color: derive(black, -60%);
}
.table-view:focused{
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-primary, 20%);
}
.table-row-cell {
    -fx-cell-size: 40px;
    -fx-border-style:solid inside;
     -fx-border-width:2;
}
.table-view .column-header-background{
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.table-view .column-header-background .label{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-text-weight:strong;
    -fx-border-style:solid inside;
    -fx-border-width:2;
    -fx-border-radius:20;
    -fx-padding:7;
    -fx-font-size:18;
 }
.table-view .column-header {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
 }
.table-view .table-cell{
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-font-size:15;
    -fx-alignment:center;
    -fx-border-style:solid inside;
    -fx-border-width:1;
}

.table-row-cell:focused, .table-cell:focused{
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
.table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-primary;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
 }

.table-row-cell:empty{
    -fx-background-color:white;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
 }

.table-column{
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
 }
.table-row-cell:even{
    -fx-background-color: derive(white, -10%);
 }
.table-row-cell:odd{
     -fx-background-color: white;
 }
 .table-row-cell:even:hover{
     -fx-background-color:pink;
 }
 .table-row-cell:odd:hover{
    -fx-background-color: skyblue;
 }

.table-row-cell:even:empty{
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.table-row-cell:odd:empty{
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
 }
.table-row-cell:selected .table-cell{
    -fx-text-fill: white;
 }
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Your answer doesn't specifically target the problem in my question and you shared the whole table css. I was expecting someone to find the mistake in my css and point out what should be changed in it. After going through all of it, i was able to identify the lacking in my css. Your answer was helpful so +1 but not specific so i'll post the main answer so that next time anyone bumps into this question, they can easily identify the solution, instead of going through all the css. Your answer is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the `TableView` css suggested by Tule Simon, I realized some css classes were missing. 
To remove the border from table header, use:

```
.table-view .column-header
{
   -fx-border-style: none;
}
```

To make the text in the cells appear white:

```
.table-cell
{
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I could have pointed that out but Your css had too many unspecified values... So I purposely posted the entire customization css so you could get all you needed and even add more customization to it..

Comment: My css was very much minimal and the mistake would have been easier to identify. if i wanted full customization, i would've searched for it but i wanted to know where i went wrong. Since you say you posted it all on purpose, i'll give you that and accept your answer, because your answer was helpful but please be more specific next time.